# How to capture html form submission using jQuery to delete sessionStorage data

Tags: jquery, form-submit, session-storage

I am using `sessionStorage` to capture certain form field values so as to be able to retain them in case of page refresh (eg. for instances like input errors etc). My code is working fine.

Comment: You can simply do the preventDefault() to stop the normal submission, run the clear storage code, then submit form with `$('#myForm').submit()` or you can just make the submit button a simple button which by default, does not submit the form, then do the same thing, run clear storage then submit. This should be after your form is validated, in other words, it is at the time you are sure that the form can be submitted

Comment: I am getting `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error on `form.submit()` when using your alt suggestion. The first one I have already used - no result.

Comment: can you update the question with your attempted code so we can get a clearer picture of how it is structured

Comment: Added codes for both the situations.

Comment: Does the storage clear work if you don't submit in case 2? Maybe you need to do this clear after the submit, for example, in the success page or whatever screen you show afterwards

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Yea so the issue is the clear line then

Comment: Do you get any errors in console? I think you should able to run the command in console or check hat is in sessionStorage in console

Comment: _Yea so the issue is the clear line then _ : No, it isn't. I have tried `sessionStorage.clear();` outside of form submit **OR** button `click` function and it clears the session storage cleanly. Please **Check** my new **edit**.

Comment: Then clear storage after submit, in the success page or whatever page that shows after you submit

Comment: That would amount to calling `sessionStorage.clear()` from another page. How do you do that?

Comment: are you not in control of the other page?